# Populating select list from a taxonomy term field

Tags: 7, forms

I'm trying to populate a select list dynamically by pulling its values from a taxonomy term field linked to the current-user account. Just to clarify, below function is a hook defined by a module that came with a custom installation profile. It is basically used to create fields on a specific form.
So, my custom module has-

```
function some_function_attributes() {


      global $user;
      $user_fields = user_load($user->uid);
      $termid = $user_fields->field_user_organization['und']['0']['tid'];
      $taxonomy_term = taxonomy_term_load($termid);
      //dsm($taxonomy_term);
      $options = field_get_items('taxonomy_term', $taxonomy_term, 'field_org_environment','select');
      dsm($options);
      return array(
        'environment' => array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'options' => $options,
        'name' => t('Environment'),
        )
      );
    }
```

---

Allowed values in the field (for this user)-

E1|Env1

E2|Env2

---

Here's the devel screenshot for `dsm($options);`
[image]

So, its populating the right field but not in the way it should.

---

Actual form element looks like this-
[image]

Currently, its just returning the array and I can't figure out what I missed. Been banging my head to the wall for this- 
How would I populate Env1 and Env2 in this select-list ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to reformat the `options` array to be in the form `'return value' => 'display value'`. See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x#options

Comment: Thanks.I had a look at your link. It says 'return value' => 'display value' could be used when the return values are specific. But mine aren't, they change depending on the logged-in user. Could you elaborate if I misunderstood ?

Comment: By 'specific value' it means that the array key will be actually what goes to the DB. Otherwise, it is still the array index, i.e. 0, 1, 2.... Given the question, I think you need exactly specific values, otherwise the same array keys will have different values for different users and you will put wrong information in the DB.

Comment: Makes sense, so I need to change the format in $options = field_get_items('taxonomy_term', $taxonomy_term, 'field_org_environment','select'); Here in the params- I have $taxonomy_term which is the term name linked to the user and 'field_org_environment' is the vocab field (widget: select-list) I'm trying to populate as a select-list. Excuse my noobish behavior, How do you recommend I do it to be in the form 'return value' => 'display value' ?

Comment: I see you have the values E1, E2... but where do you get the descriptive label from, i.e. Env1, Env2 ?
Also, try dpm() in place of dsm(), you may like the representation better :)